# Impersonation using EWS (not the Managed API)

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to use Impersonation in EWS without using the Managed API?

I read through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice(v=exchg.80).aspx) page, and it doesn't seem to help.

I want to be able to create events on user's calendars by sending SOAP requests, rather than using the managed API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure using Impersonation just involves setting the Impersonation SOAP header eg

```html
<soap:Header>
  <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    <t:ConnectingSID>
      <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>alisa@contoso.com</t: PrimarySmtpAddress>
    </t:ConnectingSID>
  </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
</soap:Header>
```

I would suggest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722378(v=exchg.150).aspx is a better reference

cheers
Glen

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @Glen! Just one further question: is there some authentication process to go through before I can send this request, or is sending this SOAP request all I have to do to get an appointment to show up?

Comment: Impersonation must be enabled via RBAC first https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204095(v=exchg.140).aspx or you will get an error saying that Impersonation is not allowed. Authentication is just the same as any other EWS request (eg either Basic or NTLM).

Comment: I guess my question should have been "Can I authenticate via sending a SOAP request, and not the C# API". I'd assume that this is possible, but couldn't find an example on the MSDN reference. Apologies if this is a stupid question, but this is entirely new territory for me. Once again, thanks for all your help, @Glen Scales.

Comment: Yes but SOAP is just the payload of your request no authentication is set within SOAP, the authentication headers are the same as any other http request so you can use what ever library/language you want. Depending how you have Exchange setup it may accept Basic Auth or may require you to use NTLM the later be a little harder to use in some open source libraries.